# python dictionary does not get updated in a loop

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I have 40 tags, I have made bigrams with them. I want to have a dictionary which consists of other dictionaries of the bigrams and their probabilities. something like this:

```
dict={'tag1' : {'tag1': 0.7, 'tag2': 0.3},
'tag2' : {'tag1': 0.4, 'tag2': 0.6}
}
```

I wrote a code which calculates the probability of the bigrams and puts them in a dictionary, and a loop that assigns them to another dictionary. But the problem is just the last bigram and its probability will be assigned. I mean the loop does not get updated. would please tell me what seems to be the problem?
this is my code:

```
each_state_bi_prob={}
transition_probability={}

for i in bi_TAGS:
    if i in bi_states:
        prob_bi_states=bi_states.count(i)/states.count(i[1])
        each_state_bi_prob[i]=prob_bi_states

    else:
        prob_bi_states=0.0001
        each_state_bi_prob[i]=prob_bi_states

for i in TAGS:
    for k,v in each_state_bi_prob.items():
        if k[0]==i:
            transition_probability[i]={k[1]:v}
```

Comment: Do you have similar tags in bi_TAGS and bi_states?  I.e. you are only updating the value of for example 'tag1'.

Comment: The code cannot be run because the input (bi_TAGS etc.) is missing.

Comment: To Michael: I wrote some parts of the code, the input is not missing

Comment: To Pathoren: Yeah there are similar items in bi_states